# Ansible - ignore_errors WHEN

Tags: ansible

Ansible 2.0.4.0

There are about three tasks which randomly fails. The output of the fail is:

```
OSError: [Errno 32] 
Broken pipefatal: [machine1]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", "stdout": ""}
```

Is it possible to ignore the error, if `Errno 32` is in the output of the error.

```
- name: This task sometimes fails
  shell: fail_me!
  ignore_errors: "{{ when_errno32 }}"
```

I"m aware this is a workaround.
Solving the 'real' problem could take up way more time.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use [`failed_when`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_error_handling.html#controlling-what-defines-failure) to control when a task should fail in Ansible, but you cannot use [`ignore_errors`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_error_handling.html#ignoring-failed-commands) for a specific return code, it is a simple yes/no switch.

So in your case you can add an expression:

```
- name: This task sometimes fails
  shell: fail_me!
  register: fail_me
  failed_when: "fail_me.rc != 0 and fail_me.rc != 32"
```

Answer (score -4):

You can also try with `ignore_errors`.

> ```
> - name: This task sometimes fail & igonre that tasks and execute next task
>
>   shell: fail_me!
>
>   ignore_errors: true
> ```