# Best practice for running an ansible role conditionally

Tags: ansible

Is there a standard or best practice for running roles conditionally?

If I have the following basic playbook:

```
---
- hosts: prod
  gather_facts: false
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  vars_files:
    - variables/vars.yml
  pre_tasks:
    - name: check app existence
      command: ls /data/myapp
      # Store the resuts here
      register: app_exists   
      ignore_errors: yes
  roles:
    - os_base_setup
    - selinux_setup
    - libsemanage_install
    ...
    # Conditionally run this role
    - - { role: app_clean_install, when: app_exists|failed }
    - post_install_config
    - cleanup
...
```

Downsides I can see to this method:

This always reports the 'pre task' as having made a 'change'.

It also reports each individual task with the 'skipped' role as being skipping, instead of just skipping the entire role.

Comment: Typing a question mark somewhere does not necessarily make it a question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback... the question was not stated clearly, so I've made an edit.

Answer (score 1):

> This always reports the 'pre task' as having made a 'change'.

Use

```
changed_when: false
```

when you execute a shell command and you know, that it gathers just information, but does not change anything.

> It also reports each individual task with the 'skipped' role as being skipping, instead of just skipping the entire role.

Set in your `ansible.cfg`

```
stdout_callback = skippy
```

to ignore skipped tasks.

> Is there anyway to stop this pre_task from logging the error when the test fails?

It is not possible prevent the logging of an error. But it is possible to ignore an error with the following option:

```
failed_when: false
```

In this case the error is logged but the playbook does not stop the execution. This is necessary to handle the error in the playbook. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42659299/402322) for an example.

Comment: Is there anyway to stop this pre_task from logging the error when the test fails? atm the first task logs a bunch of red error text.